# Handling long (> 5mins) requests from application deployed in WebLogic 12c

Tags: oracle, timeout, weblogic12c, jta

We have a problem at hand with a long service request to retrieve a huge amount of data which takes around 5 minutes to complete. We are using EJB and native JDBC to establish requests. Is there a way to extend the transaction timeout for this one particular request (that is overwriting the timeout configs in the domain's JTA) or do we have to increase the domain's JTA transaction timeout to 5 minutes? But the latter seems to be unfavorable since it might provoke database deadlock. Are there any other solutions you may suggested that is more robust and safe? Could we perhaps set the transaction timeout at a different level apart from Domain level? Looking forward to your reply soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JTA timeout can ba set at the EJB level. Read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/ejb/DDreference-ejb-jar.html#wp1116332) for details.

Comment: We are using EJB's annotation, we tried to use the equivalent @weblogic.javaee.TransactionTimeoutSeconds but with no luck. It seems the timeout seconds specified in the program has got overridden by the timeout seconds configured at the weblogic's domain. Is there anyway to enforce the one specify in the EJB by not the one configured in the admin console.

Comment: It is the good annotation.
When you say "We are using EJB and native JDBC to establish requests", does it mean you are not using a WebLogic Datasource but you are creating the sql connection directly from the EJB using the jdbc driver ?